# Bounded-Waiting Mutual Exclusion with Compare-and-Swap

Tags: operating-system, synchronization

I added comments to each line to the best of my understanding, but I still don't get why we set `waiting[j] = false;` at the end without running process j's critical section. In my opinion, `waiting[j] = false;` should be replaced with `i = j;` so when it loops again, we run process j's critical section. Or else we'll always be running process i's critical section!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a process to enter its critical section, `waiting[i]` must be false, but `waiting[i]` can only be set to false if a process is leaving its critical section by calling `waiting[j] = false`, which I take to mean that now process `j` can enter its critical section prompting process `i` to wait. I'm still learning these concepts so I'm not 100% sure. Abraham and Silberschatz 9th edition does not do a very thorough job of explaining these algorithms.

Comment: I'm just going to accept your answer because right after the final exam, I forgot everything I learned in this course LOL

Answer (score 1):

### Validity of the Algorithm

First, it is important to note that this algorithm solves the **critical section problem** **only** when there are **two** processes (here they are referred to as process 0 and process 1).

Next, as per the **convention** in *Operating System Concepts by Abraham and Silberschatz . Peter B Galvin . Gerge Gagne*, **i** refers to **one of** the processes amongst 0 and 1 and **j** refers to the **other** process.

#### Mapping of right code to right process

Having said that, it must be noted that **this code is for the process i**. The **code for process j** would be obtained by **interchanging i and j** in the given code. (In my opinion this is what caused confusion to you, since you said the following)

> should be replaced with i = j;  so when it loops again, we run process j's critical section. Or else we'll always be running process i's critical section!

#### Finally, consequences of `waiting[j] = false` (which happens in Process i)

Now, both these codes would execute as **two different** processes in a system. So as soon as you set `waiting[j] = false` in the last line of **Process i** following events occur:

- The condition in `while(waiting[j] && key == 1)` for the **code of Process j** (*Note that the code for Process j is obtained by replacing i with j as explained in the previous heading of Mapping of right code to right process*) turns out to be **false** and therefore **Process j resumes** it's execution by entering the critical section.
- Meanwhile, Process i loops back into the outermost `while(true)` loop, **setting** **waiting[i]** to **true**, **key** to **1** and **waiting** by looping over in the `while(waiting[i] && key == 1)` loop.